# whats wrong. when i call foreign key

Tags: mysql

```
Create table APPLICANT
(
Applicant_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Applicant_Name nvarchar (25) NOT NULL,
Father_Name nvarchar (25),
Gender nvarchar (15),
Applicant_DOB datetime,
Qualifaction nvarchar (45),
Application_Id varchar (15),
PRIMARY KEY (Applicant_ID, Applicant_Name)

 );

 create table APPLICATION
(
Application_ID varchar (10),
Application_Name nvarchar(25),
Applicant_ID varchar (10),
Applicant_Name nvarchar (25),
primary key (Application_ID) 
);


Create table CELL_NUMBER
(
Cell_No varchar (15) NOT NULL ,
Applicant_ID varchar (10),
Applicant_Name nvarchar (25),
Primary Key (Cell_No)

);


Alter table CELL_NUMBER
add constraint fk_applicant_id foreign key (Applicant_ID) references APPLICANT (Applicant_ID);

Alter table CELL_NUMBER
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_applicant_name foreign key (Applicant_Name) references APPLICANT (Applicant_Name);
```

---

show this error

```
Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 34
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'APPLICANT' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_applicant_id'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 34
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Comment: Are you positively sure that you are using MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can't create a foreign key that references just one column of a primary key pair.</strike>

```
Alter table CELL_NUMBER ADD CONSTRAINT fk_applicant 
  foreign key (Applicant_ID, Applicant_Name) references 
  APPLICANT (Applicant_ID, Applicant_Name)
```

<strike>This is because your foreign key needs to identify one row in the APPLICANT table, and since your primary keys reference two columns, you can't just use one column to generate the foreign key.</strike>

EDIT: You CAN reference just one column of a composite primary key, as corrected by Justin

Answer (score 0):

The data types of the two columns (foreign key and referenced key) must match exactly. Because `Applicant_Name` is defined as `nvarchar(25) NOT NULL` in `APPLICANT`, it must be defined as such in `CELL_NUMBER` (the `NOT NULL` being the missing piece).